# Incorrect timezone and timestamp with PHP Datetime objects and strtotime

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp, timezone, offset

My server timezone is UTC,
but when I create a DateTime object or when I convert a date to a timestamp with strtotime, the result is wrong.

I have made a simple code:

```
$date_init = '2020-07-25 13:00:00';
$dt = new DateTime( $date_init, new DateTimeZone( 'UTC' ) );

$timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
$strtotime = strtotime( $date_init . ' UTC' );
$timestamp = $dt->getTimestamp();
$date_final = $dt->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s P e' );
```

When I echo these values:

```
$date_init = 2020-07-25 13:00:00
$timezone = UTC
$strtotime = 1595700000
$timestamp = 1595700000
$date_final = 2020-07-25 13:00:00 -05:00 UTC
```

Even the timestamp is wrong (1595700000 = 2020-07-25 18:00:00 UTC) ([online converter](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php)).

The expected result is :

```
$timestamp = 1595682000
$strtotime = 1595682000
$date_final = 2020-07-25 13:00:00 +00:00 UTC
```

I don't understand what happen, can anyone help?

PHP version: 7.3.19

Answer (score 0):

Provide the timezone as the second parameter when creating the DateTime object.

```
$date_init = '2020-07-25 13:00:00';
$dt = new DateTime( $date_init , new DateTimeZone("UTC"));

echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s P e');
```

Comment: Same result :(
2020-07-25 13:00:00 -05:00 UTC

Comment: Looks like `date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s P e', $timestamp )` creates a new date object and ignores the set timezone. You can use `DateTime::format` instead, I updated my answer.

Comment: Same result with DateTime::format unfortunately (2020-07-25 13:00:00 -05:00 UTC). Thank you for helping out. I think the most basic problem is that strtotime( '2020-07-25 13:00:00 UTC' ) = 1595700000 instead of 1595682000. I guess the problem comes from a server or a PHP config, but I don't know which one. (It is working fine on my local dev site).